# migrating a dump from neo4j 3.5.6 community edition to neo4j 4.1 enterprise edition

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to migrate a database dump from 3.5.6 community edition neo4j to 4.1 enterprise version.  I know that the only way to load a dump from a community edition is to tar the dump and load it in the newer version.  I followed couple of guides to do that and made sure that dbms.allow_upgrade=true is in the neo4j.conf file.  However, I'm getting the following error while trying to start the service. Although, I have tested on 3.5.6 to 3.5.21 migration and it worked fine
 `org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleAdapter$3@d520439' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Cannot map files with a filePageSize (0) that is less than 8 bytes | GBPTree[file:/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/vodafone/neostore.id]".`

the size of neostore.id is 9B and it was always like that just wondering why it is an issue in migrating from neo4j 3.5.xx to neo4j 4.1

Comment: According to [Neo4j documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.1/upgrade/planning/) upgrading from 3.5 to 4.1 but first you have to upgrade to the latest patch of 3.5. 
Are you upgrading from 3.5.6 or from 3.5.21 to 4.1?

Comment: Yup I upgraded it to 3.5.21 first and then to 4.1 but without using the load/import commands rather tar the existing load and untar it